# CRON JOB - LARAVEL - OUTPUT

Tags: laravel, cron

Hi I'm running CRON JOB with Laravel

Function declaration in Laravel

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    echo "test CRON JOB\n";
    $file1 = '1.log';
    $file2 = '2.log';
    $schedule->command('command1')->sendOutputTo($file1);
    $schedule->command('command2')->sendOutputTo($file2);

}
```

CRON JOB - Setting

```
pathToArtisan schedule:run 2>&1 >> /home/log/cron_output.log
```

Log file output (cron_output.log)

```
test CRON JOB
Running scheduled command: '/opt/alt/php55/usr/bin/php' 'artisan'command1 > '1.log' 2>&1 &
Running scheduled command: '/opt/alt/php55/usr/bin/php' 'artisan' command2 > '2.log' 2>&1 &
```

The echo in the function schedule is displayed but the ones inside my command 1 and command 2 are not.

I tried

```
echo "test"; $this->info('test');
```

No files 1.log or 2.log where created neither /home/log/ or where the Kernel.php file is or Command folder

Any ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: Your commands should use `$this->info('test')`, `$this->error('test')`, etc. to output text.

Comment: Does not seem to change anything.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should use the built-in [task output](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling#task-output) method in Laravel.

For example:

```
$file = 'command1_output.log';
$schedule->command('command1')
         ->sendOutputTo($file);
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case I prefer `appendOutputTo`.

Answer (score 7):

Everything is ok now.

```
$schedule->command('command1')
     ->sendOutputTo($file);
```

and inside your command

```
$this->info('test')
```

The files are created in the root folder of my application so I didn't see them !

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
$schedule->command('my:command')
     ->daily()
     ->onSuccess(function () {
         // The task succeeded...
//set flag here and store to DB
     })
     ->onFailure(function () {
         // The task failed...
//set flag here and store to DB
     });
```

Show list in admin dashboard so that you can check logs using these flags(cron status)